# Offload image loading to CDN on the fly

Tags: php, cdn, tiles, bandwidth

We are running a tile serve which generates images on the fly but caches some to a CDN.  When we get a request for a given tile e.g. http://mydomain.com/x/y/z/tile.png, can we choose whether to serve up the local image or to serve up the image on the CDN (if we know there is one cached for the given tile)?  And if so, will it be served via our server and thus not actually reduce bandwith?

Note, the client will make a request for an image file and needs to receive an image back.  We cannot send the client a url for the CDN and then have the client make a second request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't trigger a `30x` header redirect

```
header("Location: http://cdn.example.com/.....");
```

there is no way to do this. You would have to fetch the image from the CDN on server side and pass it through, rendering the point of the CDN moot.

Comment: We certainly have the flexibility to trigger a header redirect on the tile server (as its just a php page).  Will that work for the client?  They request an image, follow the 30x and get the image from the CDN instead?

Comment: @user depends on what the client is. A browser will follow the redirect. A `curl` with the `followlocation` option turned off (or whatever it's named, can't remember) will not follow, but return an empty body.